# ETIMEDOUT connecting to MySql from Lambda

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to a MySql RDS instance from a Lambda function and getting an ETIMEDOUT error

- The Lambda is not part of a VPC
- The RDS instance is available publicly, I can connect to it from my laptop using MySqlWorkbench
- The RDS instance's security group has inbound rules configured for all ports and 0.0.0.0/0
- The Lambda's execution role has many policies (probably too many) including RDSFullAccess, LambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole, ec2:*, even AdministratorAccess!)

Again, the code executes locally, connects to and queries the RDS instance just fine. Executing the same code in Lambda throws the ETIMEDOUT error

Similar posts are resolved by adding the Lambda to the RDS instance's VPC, or by configuring the inbound rules on the database's security group. Nothing seems to work.

Since I can connect to the database from my laptop just fine, my hunch is that it's a problem with the Lambda

Are there additional policies I should attach to the Lambda's execution role?

Is there any other reason the Lambda would time out connecting to a publicly available database?

Additional info:

The Lambda is not running in a VPC. It runs on Node and connects to MySql using the mysql package v2.18.1 and is deployed using Serverless with the following config:

```
foo:
  handler: functions/handlers.foo
  timeout: 20
  events:
    - http:
        path: /path/{pathParameter}/foo
        method: get
        cors: true
        caching:
          enabled: true
          ttlInSeconds: 3600
          cacheKeyParameters:
            - name: request.path.pathParameter
```

In the Lambda I try connecting with this function (which, again, works fine when I execute the function on my laptop):

```
function openDbConnection() {
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'db-name.cgwxrjuo6oyd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: 'db-name'
});  
try {
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        console.log("Database is ", connection.state)
        if (err) {
          return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
        }
      
        console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
      });        
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Database is ", connection.state)
    console.log("Error connecting to MySql: ", error);
}

return connection;
```

}

The database username and password are retrieved from environment variables that are published to the Lambda with Serverless using a .env.yml file:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221'
  environment: ${file(.env.yml):}
```

Below are the Cloudwatch logs for a single execution, which I'm having trouble making sense of. Entries appear out of sequence:

```
|   timestamp   | message |
|---------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1626209636788 | START RequestId: e3e3ceb7-bb55-4c3e-8392-38e08401f679 Version: $LATEST                                                                                   |
| 1626209636791 | 2021-07-13T20:53:56.790Z adfc1cd5-e4be-40b7-970c-d38acabeb199 INFO Database is  disconnected                                                             |
| 1626209636791 | 2021-07-13T20:53:56.791Z adfc1cd5-e4be-40b7-970c-d38acabeb199 ERROR error: connect ETIMEDOUT                                                             |
| 1626209636791 | 2021-07-13T20:53:56.791Z adfc1cd5-e4be-40b7-970c-d38acabeb199 INFO An error occured querying MySql:  connect ETIMEDOUT                                   |
| 1626209636792 | 2021-07-13T20:53:56.792Z adfc1cd5-e4be-40b7-970c-d38acabeb199 INFO Database is  disconnected                                                             |
| 1626209636792 | 2021-07-13T20:53:56.792Z adfc1cd5-e4be-40b7-970c-d38acabeb199 ERROR error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.                            |
| 1626209636793 | 2021-07-13T20:53:56.792Z adfc1cd5-e4be-40b7-970c-d38acabeb199 INFO An error occured querying MySql:  Connection lost: The server closed the connection. | 1626209636803 | END RequestId: e3e3ceb7-bb55-4c3e-8392-38e08401f679                                                                                                   |
| 1626209636803 | REPORT RequestId: e3e3ceb7-bb55-4c3e-8392-38e08401f679 Duration: 9.32 ms Billed Duration: 10 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 79 MB              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you share some more information? How your Lambda is configured? Is it running in a VPC? How long does it take for you to get that error?

Comment: The timeout happens immediately, so it's not a networking issue. It also appears that the connection is being closed from the server. I would try to figure out why that is happening.

Comment: I was able to get this working by migrating from mysql to mysql2. I'm not endorsing mysql2 over mysql as both appear very popular and well supported, though in this case I was able to successfully open a connection, execute the query and close the connection without error using mysql2